# c# Having users choose from elements in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a project in which users enter a job description, hours needed, and hourly pay for 5 jobs. Once entered they must choose 2 of the jobs they entered to combine into one job. I'm unsure how to retrieve the job number that they enter from the array (jobArray) (job 1 and job2 for example).

So if they enter in job 1 as mowing, and job 2 as trimming they should have the option to combine both to make mowing and trimming.

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated.

```
   namespace DemoJobs
    {
    class Class2
    {
        public static Job[] jobArray = new Job[5];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string option;
            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Menu");
                Console.WriteLine("\t1. Enter Jobs");
                Console.WriteLine("\t2. Combine 2 Jobs");
                Console.WriteLine("\t3. Display All Jobs");
                Console.WriteLine("\t4. Exit");

                option = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (option)
                {
                    case "1":
                        Console.Clear();
                        EnterJobs();
                        break;


                    case "2":
                        Console.Clear();
                         //CombineJobs();
                        break;

                    case "3": //display jobs
                        DisplayAllJobs();
                        break;

                    case "4":
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Option invalid.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                }

            } while (option != "4");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit the window.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void EnterJobs()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.Length; i++)
            {
                // int totFee;
                Job job = new Job();

                Console.WriteLine("Job " + i);

                Console.WriteLine("Enter a job description.");
                job.Description = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of hours required to complete the job.");
                job.hoursToComplete = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the hourly rate for the job.");
                job.hourlyRate = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                jobArray[i] = job;

                //calcing total fee
                job.totalFee = job.hourlyRate * job.hoursToComplete;


            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");


        } //end of enterjobs


        //combining jobs
        private static void CombineJobs(Job first, Job second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Which 2 jobs would you like to combine?");
            first.Description = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void DisplayAllJobs()
        {

           // jobArray.ToList().Sort();  

            //sorting jobs from totalFee
            Array.Sort(jobArray);
            //printing array
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[1].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[2].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[3].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(jobArray[4].ToString());  

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: this question is a mess, i dont even know what the point of CombineJobs() is, why does it change the first jobs description?

Explain what "combining jobs" actually means, and well help you implement it

Comment: Yes you should be making a local variable to hold the input ReadLine and then check it against first.Description.

Comment: I would print out the list of jobs with their indexes (or some other ID) and ask the user to select the first id, then ask them for the 2nd id.  You can then get these from the array and combine.

Comment: @downrep_nation combinejobs will execute when the user presses 2 on the menu to prompt the user to select 2 jobs to combine together(the title, hours and pay), i meant to delete the   first.description line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the array like this.

```
Job jobToFind = jobArray.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Description.Equals(first.Description));
Job job2ToFind = jobArray.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Description.Equals(second.Description));
```

and then combine jobs as you see fit.

```
newJob.Description = jobToFind.Description + job2ToFind.Description; 
// newJob.Pay = more combining here etc.
```